# Retrieve origina context from callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this

I have a JavaScript class with two methods like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rauthvw1/).

```
var MyObject = function () {};

MyObject.prototype = {
    open: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self);

        $('#a').click('', self.other);
    },
    other: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

var myobject = new MyObject;

myobject.open();
```

In the `console.log` in the `other` function, `this` is the HTML node that the event listens to and not the `MyObject` object as in the `open` function.

How can I retrieve the `MyObject` object from the function `other` when used as a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) passing the `this` context as 2nd parameter:

```
var MyObject = function () {};

MyObject.prototype = {
    open: function () {
        $('#a').click($.proxy(this.other, this));
    },
    other: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

var myobject = new MyObject;

myobject.open();
```

When clicking on `#a` the `MyObject.other()` function will be called with a `this` instance referring to `MyObject`.

[JSFIddle with code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/lorestar/9s5eoeah/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `this` into the `eventData` parameter of `.click`.

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    open: function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self);

        $('#a').click(self, self.other);
    },
    other: function (event) {
        console.log(event.data); // should output your object
    }
};
```

The reason you're seeing your html object went logging `this` in other is because other is being run under the context of the `.click` callback and `this` is referring to it's caller --> the html object.